# How to list all http:// links in mysql via phpMyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Could you please help me for list all links in xf_post table by phpmyAdmin.

All links begin with http://
I just want list of links not whole row entry. Sample query result should be like below. Thanks for your support.

http: //www.mibsasquerido.com.ar/Assets/Personagens/che-habano.jpg

http: //rapidshare.de/files/782144/MATLAP_T_RK_E_KAYNAKLAR.rar.html

**Sample rows of database :**

SELECT * FROM `xf_post`

```
 CENTER][B]Che Guevara[/B]
    [B][/B]
    [IMG]http://www.mibsasquerido.com.ar/Assets/Personagens/che-habano.jpg[/IMG]  [/CENTER]
    1928 yılında Arjantin’in Rosaria kentinde doğdu. Tıp öğrenimi gördü. Öğrenciyken okuluna bir yıl ara verip, Güney Amerika kıtasında geziye çıktı.
```

2nd sample row

```
Matlab hakkında türkçe kaynaklar

[url=http://rapidshare.de/files/782144/MATLAP_T_RK_E_KAYNAKLAR.rar.html]DOWNLOAD[/url]
```

3rd sample row

```
[CENTER][IMG]http://www.kimkimdir.gen.tr/foto/372.jpg[/IMG]

[B][SIZE=17px]Mehmet Akif Ersoy (1873 - 1936)[/SIZE][/B][/CENTER]


Türk, şair. İstiklal Marşı'nı yazmış, günlük konuşma dilinin şiirle
```

[table screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/svgce.png)

Comment: you want only the  value contained in img column name  ???' how is named  the corresponding column in your xf:post table ??

Comment: The links are always between `[IMG]` and only 1 per row? If so maybe something like `select substr(row, locate('[IMG]', row), (locate('[/IMG]', row) - locate('[IMG]', row)))
from test
where row like '%http%'`

Comment: Not only image I want to check broken links so I need to list all links which are begins with 'http://' I also added table's screen shot to my question.

Comment: Mysql doesn't have a regex extraction method built in. You'll need to use a `like` to pull all records then some processing language/program.

Comment: thanks. how to list eveything between [img] [/img] tags on this  table ; SELECT * FROM `xf_post` WHERE 1